# Send email using phpmailer

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmailer

I am trying to send mail using PHPMailer my controller code here

```
public function register(){ $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Usename Name', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[30]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email ID', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[employer_registration.email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile', 'Mobile', 'trim|required|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|md5');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('employer/emp_register');
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'mobile' => $this->input->post('mobile'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password')
        );
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
    // insert form data into database
        if ($this->Employer_model->insertUser($data))
        {
            require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
            require 'class.phpmailer.php';
            $mail = new PHPMailer;
            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $subject = 'Testing Email';
            $username = $username;
            $email = $email;
            $body = "Thank you for register your username is $username";
            $mail->AddAddress($email);
            $mail->IsMail();
            $mail->From = 'domainname.com';
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->Body  = $body;
            $mail->Send();

            if(!$mail->send())
            {
                echo "<script>alert('Sorry! mail not sent')</script>";
               echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            }
            else
                {
                echo "<script>alert('Email sent to $email mail id')</script>";
                 }
    }}}
```

I have downloaded phpmailer folder from github, include it on my project  PHPMailerAutoload file still after successful registration i unable to send mail to registered email id . i got error like **Mailer Error: Could not instantiate mail function.**

Comment: Codeigniter has a email library.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: use CI mail library.

Comment: You've made so many mistakes in this it's not worth pointing them out; Base your code on the examples provided with PHPMailer, use [the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), and read the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `SMTP` authentication but you're not actually defining any host, which is required:

Ex: `$mail->Host = "smtp.example.com";`

Put that changed with your domain after `$mail->isSMTP();`.

Also, optionally, you can provide a username and password like this, if you need:

`$mail->Username = 'username';
 $mail->Password = 'password';`