# How to send an email with PHPmailer

Tags: phpmailer

In order to use PHPmailer I installed vendor on my index file. Vendor contains the autoloader. I have seen that we can use his own SMTP or in localhost. in my case I want to do it in localhost.

I tried to change the lines after [mail function] in "php.ini" with my informations but it didn't help. here is the code:

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {

    $mail->setFrom('myEmail@gmail.com', 'Darth Vader');

    $mail->addAddress('myEmail@gmail.com', 'Emperor');

    $mail->Subject = 'Force';

    $mail->Body = 'There is a great disturbance in the Force.';

    $mail->send();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
echo $e->errorMessage();
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Here is what I get on firefox on localhost: "Could not instantiate mail function.".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send email using phpmailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41142361/send-email-using-phpmailer)

Comment: Please read [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#could-not-instantiate-mail-function) which explains the details behind this problem, and how to solve it.